# Are there js intellisense files for underscore and other js libraries?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, intellisense, vsdoc

There are `-intellisense.js` or `-vsdoc.js` files for adding complete jQuery and jQuery Validation intellisense to Visual Studio - i.e. namespaces, functions, arguments, return values, remarks, etc.

- Is there such a thing for Underscore? You get basic intellisense by adding the library to the `_references.js` file, but what about the rest as detailed above?
- Is there perhaps a list somewhere with all currently available intellisense files? For example, would be awesome to get these for: Knockout, Google APIs such as maps and geolocation, RequireJS, Bootstrap, ...

Comment: [Intellisense for Google Maps v3](http://gmapvsdoc.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not seem to be a way to do this.